# Java аннотации - реализация бизнес логики

Tags: java, аннотации

Хочу написать свои аннотации, так как возникло несколько идей, но не могу понять как это сделать. Вроде легко, но вопрос: как к аннотации прикрепить бизнес логику? Что я могу сделать с теми  данными которые мне пришли в аннотации. пример: `@Annotation(SomeValue.VALUE)`. И как мне взять это велью с сделать с ним какую-то бизнес логику? Например засунуть в какой-то метод из другой библиотеки прокрутить его и вернуть значения..

Comment: Если Вы этого не понимаете, значит, оно Вам не нужно.

Comment: @kff может тогда можно объяснить?

Comment: Бизнес-логика прикрепляется не к аннотации, а к аннотированному классу. Бизнес-данные хранятся в экземпляре класса, а параметры аннотации просто настраивают её поведение. Кроме того, бизнес-логика на аннотациях обычно реализуется в составе JavaEE контейнеров.

Comment: Точнее говоря, бизнес-логика связана с аннотацией, но применяется к аннотированным объектам. А вообще, Ваш вопрос слишком общий.

Comment: @kff ну в общих чертах я это так и понимаю. но это как раз то что я и знал. я вот тогда хочу узнать. как тогда написать аннотацию.. допустим датасорс, которую я мог бы цеплять за любой класс и через нее подключать датасорс?

Comment: А что у Вас в качестве JavaEE-контейнера?

Comment: @kff tomcat7 ...

Comment: Мне казалось, аннотации используются через рефлексию.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Для использования своей аннотации нужно:**

1. Реализовать аннотацию (`public @interface MyAnnotationExample` c типом аннотации [ElementType](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html) - например: класс/метод/конструктор/поле и т.п.).
2. Использовать эту аннотацию `MyAnnotationExample` в вашем коде (в соответствии с типом [ElementType](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html) аннотации `MyAnnotationExample`), т.е. добавить аннотацию к классу/методу/полю/и т.п.
3. Реализовать обработчик этой аннотации через [рефлексию](http://devcolibri.com/193).

**Пример #1. Аннотация на класс и чтение аннотации класса через рефлексию.**

Создадим аннотацию `MyAnnotationExampleForClass`:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(value = ElementType.TYPE) //указание что данная аннотация вешается на класс
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) //аннотация доступна в процессе работы модуля
public @interface MyAnnotationExampleForClass {

    String name() default "default name"; //в name() мы будем хранить значения аннотации
}
```

Создадим класс `MyClassExample` с использованием аннотации `MyAnnotationExampleForClass`:

```
@MyAnnotationExampleForClass(name = "this is my annotation value!!!")
public class MyClassExample {
...
}
```

Создадим класс `MyAnnotationProcessorExample` для получения значений аннотаций:

```
class MyAnnotationProcessorExample {
        MyClassExample myClass = new MyClassExample();
        //получаем нашу аннотацию из нашего объекта
        MyAnnotationExampleForClass a = myClass.getClass().getAnnotation(MyAnnotationExampleForClass.class);
    System.out.println("выводим значение аннотации = " + a.name());
    System.out.println("печатаем тип аннотации со значением = " + a.toString());
    }
```

**Пример #2. Аннотация на метод класса и чтение аннотации метода через рефлексию.**
   Добавим еще аннотацию `MyAnnotationExampleForMethod` для метода:

```
@Target(value = ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotationExampleForMethod {

    String name() default "default name 2";
}
```

Добавим в наш класс `MyClassExample` (из примера #1) новый метод `runForest()`:

```
@MyAnnotationExampleForClass(name = "this is my annotation value!!!")
public class MyClassExample {

    @MyAnnotationExampleForMethod(name = "this is my method-annotation value")
    public void runForest() { System.out.println("Our Forest run very good!"); }
}
```

Создадим класс `MyAnnotationProcessorExample2` для получения значений аннотаций:

```
class MyAnnotationProcessorExample2 {
        MyClassExample myClass = new MyClassExample();

        //получаем наш метод из нашего объекта
        Method m = tm.getClass().getMethod("runForest");

        //получаем аннотацию из нашего метода
        MyAnnotationExampleForMethod a = m.getAnnotation(TimeAnnotationMethod.class);

    System.out.println("выводим значение аннотации = " + a.name());
    System.out.println("печатаем тип аннотации со значением = " + a.toString());
    }
```

Теперь можно эти классы-обработчики `MyAnnotationProcessorExample` и `MyAnnotationProcessorExample2` использовать в нужных местах для обработки бизнес-логики.
Примеры привел самые примитивные, только для общего понимания.
Для более полноценных реализаций нужно разбираться с понятием java reflection.

**Также рекомендую посмотреть темы:**

1. [В каких случаях на практике применять рефлексию, аннотации?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/598005/%D0%92-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8F%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)
2. [Зачем создавать собственные аннотации?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546038/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)
3. [Аннотация в Java EE](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/522480/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-java-ee)

Comment: ооо. это то, что нужно. спасибо